# How to execute bool via WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I use CreateQuery for entities, but how do you use it with bool type? I tried using execute method like this:

```
    public bool CheckIfBrowserExists(string name, string version)
    {
        var query =
            this.ClientRepositories
                .Proxies
                .Execute<bool>("CheckIfBrowserExists");

        return query;
    }
```

I don't know how to finish it. I have working solution via norma post service but I would like to do it via WCF Data Service if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expose a service operation returning bool and accepting parameters, as described in [WCF Data Services Operations documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668788%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

WCF Data Services exposed operations allow parameters only for `IQueryable<T>` return types (to build query expression which consequently retrieve and serialize data)

IMHO employing WCF Data Services in this case is a wrong approach, better use operation contract in standard WCF endpoint as your operation returns business logic result rather than data response for RESTful query.

Comment: I've read about that some time ago, but I think I saw it somewhere that guy used Execute method.

Comment: Execute method can be used and doesn't prohibit returning bool as well. You just can't use query options (method params) in such operations.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to return a bool from your service is the following :

```
public bool CheckIfBrowserExists(string name, string version)
    {
        var result =
            this.ClientRepositories
                .Proxies
                .Execute<IEnumerable<bool>>("CheckIfBrowserExists");

        return result.Single();
    }
```

This will return the boolean result you attempted to retrieve. in fact the execute method returns an `IEnumerable<bool>` if your data service returns `bool` for example.

Hope this helps.